# Asynch callback while Callable is running

Tags: java, callback, callable

Let's say I have a Person object:

```
public class Person {
  private String name;
  private History history;
}
```

History takes a very long time to generate, so I created a 
HistoryCallable class that implements Callable, to generate the History asynchonrously:

```
public class HistoryCallable implements Callable<HistoryResult> {

  @Override
  public HistoryResult call() {
   // do a lot of stuff
  }
```

Now let's say I have a list of Persons, and I want to generate the History for each one. I create a List of HistoryCallable's, and submit each one to an ExecutorService:

```
ExecutorService execService =  Executors.newFixedThreadPool();
List<Future<HistoryResult>> results = new ArrayList<>();

for (final Callable<HistoryResult> historyCallable : historyCallables) {
  final Future<HistoryResult> future = execService.submit(historyCallable);
  results.add(mixingThread);
}
```

My problem is: these HistoryCallable instances know nothing about the Person they belong to. However, since they take a long time to complete, I need to know how each one is going, what stage they are at, etc., for each Person.

Is there anyway I can use a callback (or something else), ***not*** when each Callable has completed but rather while each one is running, letting me know the progress for each Person, without passing any Person info to each Callable?

Comment: What do you mean exaclty by "letting me know the progress"? Logger.info from the callable?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't really explain that, did I? What I mean is: let's say that from within each Callable, I loop over 100,000 urls and do something with each one. What I would like to know, *outside* the Caller, how many urls have currently been processed, for each Person. *Without* passing any Person info (id, name) to the Callable.

Comment: In the urls you parse, is there anything that identifies a person (like http://whatever.com/PersonName/ttt) ?

Comment: Nope. The HistoryResult inside each Callable is totally anonymous, it knows nothing about the Person it belongs to. Hence my problem. :)

Comment: If you don't have any information Inside HistoryResult to link your urls to a Person, I have no idea how you would know the progress without adding a list of Persons

Comment: Please let us know what you want to do with the information from the Callables. Do you need to react quasi-synchronously to each update or can you just poll asynchronously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
public class HistoryCallable implements Callable<HistoryResult> {


  private long totalItems;
  private volatile long itemsProcessed;

  @Override
  public HistoryResult call() {
   // do a lot of stuff
   // after each item:
   itemsProcessed++;
  }

  public long getItemsProcessed() {
    return itemsProcessed;
  }

  public long getTotalItems() {
    return totalItems;
  }
}



public class PersonHistoryBuilder {
  private Person person;
  private HistoryCallable callable;

  public Person getPerson() {
    return person;
  }

  public float getProgressPercent() {
    return (100.0f * callable.getItemsProcessed()) / callable.getTotalItems();
  }

}
```

Comment: Hmmm ... yes, that would more or less work for a "pull" model. ie. the "parent" (PersonHistoryBuilder) polls the Callable. Unfortunately what I need is more like a "push", ie. from within the Callable, update a counter at the parent level each time a url is processed ... Also, something else that I didn't clearly explain in my first post: there can by n HistoryCallable per Person, each one, for example, processing a fraction of the 100,000 urls ...

Comment: "update a counter at the parent level each time a url is processed" - Are you sure about that requirement? Do you need to actively react to each notification or can you do that asynchronously, e.g. update a display 10 times per second?

Comment: Do you need the notification to run in the "parent" thread, or can it run inside the callable's thread? The latter is easily solved by a simple callback interface you define yourself.

Comment: Well I *could* do that, asynchronously poll each Callable every n seconds and update accordingly. But as I said, I'd rather push this info from within each Callable to the parent, using some kind of global counter within the parent, that gets updated from within the Callable. Just not sure how that would work. What you are suggesting, on the other hand, is to define a callback interface (eg. Updateable), with method update(), have my Callable implement it to return the current amount of urls processed, then register it with the parent, and call update(), from the parent, for each Callable?

Comment: Anyway, thanks for all of your help. I accepted your first answer since it *is* a solution to my problem.

Comment: In fact, the callback idea works the other way around. The parent implements the `Updateable` and registers itself with every `Callable`. Each Callable then calls the Updateable parent whenever it has something new to tell. This implies that the callback runs inside each Callable's thread. If you don't want that you can also create a [`Queue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) and have all Callables put any notifications into that queue while the parent polls the queue for any new notifications.

Comment: Yes, I think I'm going to do it the way you originally suggested -- hold a reference to each of my Callables in the "parent" class (the one with the ExecutorService), have each one of them be updateable, and then just loop through them periodically until all tasks are finished, add up each one's count, and Bob's your uncle. Thanks again for the very helpful advice.